# Angular SQL - Is there something missing?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am trying to display a table using Angular but it won't display. Is something wrong/missing? Code below. The table is in the source code as being there, but nothing is generated inside it. I'm new to Angular.

Front-end

```
    <div ng-app="musicApp" ng-controller="musicCtrl">

<table>
  <tr ng-repeat="x in names">
    <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.SongArtist }}</td>
    <td>{{ x.SongAlbum }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('musicApp', []);
app.controller('musicCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
   $http.get("http://rhys-bennett.uk/AIDc3391265/includes/formatjson.php")
   .then(function (response) {$scope.names = response.records;});
});
</script>
```

PHP Back-end

```
    <?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");


$result = $conn->query("SELECT song_name, song_artist, song_album FROM musictable");

$outp = "";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"Name":"'  . $rs["song_name"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"SongArtist":"'   . $rs["song_artist"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"SongAlbum":"'. $rs["song_album"]     . '"}'; 
}
$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
$conn->close();

echo($outp);
?>
```

Comment: Whaaat? You are manually constructing JSON string? That's too error-prone man. Just make the right structure in PHP and then encode it with `json_encode()`

Comment: You know there's a [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function so that you don't have to cobble together the json by hand, right? Also, check your browser's network console. Is your request being sent? What's the response?

Comment: To be direct: The problem is almost certainly your manually encoded JSON.  Instead, you should simply put the records in an array then json_encode: `$json = []; while ($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {$json[] = $rs;} echo json_encode($json); die();`

Comment: It's part of the assignment to do it that way haha, I know about the encode function! It sucks because once we've done it all manually we have to do it with an MVC...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to access the `data` object in your response (`response.data.records`):

```
$http.get("http://rhys-bennett.uk/AIDc3391265/includes/formatjson.php")
 .then(function (response) {
    $scope.names = response.data.records;
 });
```

Comment: This fixed it, much appreciated!